# jQuery ajax call doesn't work with parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I want to call a web service method. here is my jQuery code:

```
  var name = $("#Name").val();
  alert(name);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "CityList.aspx/Edit",
      data: '{"name":' + name + '}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg.d);

      },
      error: function (msg) {
          alert(msg);
      }
  });
```

And here is my server side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Edit(string name)
{
    ...
}
```

When I pass the parameter, it is falling to error but I call the method without parameter everything is ok. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: data attributes should be without quotes and then check your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my data text with:  `data: '{name:"' + name + '",id:' + id + '}'` and it resolved. Thanks for you helps.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  data: '{"name":' + name + '}',
```

to

```
  data: {name:  name },
```

Comment: i tested and it sends a POST request with name parameter.http://jsfiddle.net/rKX6M/ ( check the consoel and inspect POST tab)

Comment: The error in the fiddle is because there is no such page exist in the fiddle domain. you can see that it tried to make a POST call by inspecting the NET tab and POST tab to see the params it passed, Check it with Visual studio breakppoints

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `Data` should be query string or object.